# Carregar select via ajax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, json

Estou tentando carregar um select via ajax, segue como estou fazendo:
HTML:

```html
<select id="cbplanos" class="form-control"></select>
```

Código Controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Load()
    {
        var lista = _context.PlanosServicos
        .Select(x => new { x.Id, x.Descricao });

        return Json(new { Resultado = lista });
```

}

E aqui o código AJAX:

```js
function ListarItens() {
    var url = "/PessoasServicos/Load";

    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "/PessoasServicos/Load",
        data: { tipos: $("#cbplanos").val() },
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            var selectbox = $('#cbplanos');
            $.each(data, function (i, d) {
                selectbox.append('<option value="' + d.Id + '">' + d.Descricao + '</option>');
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Porém ele não está me trazendo os valores. O que estou passando de errado?

Comment: Já inspecionou o objeto "data" no `success`? Me parece que deveria usar `data.Resultado` no `each`

Comment: Tentei desta forma, porém continuou com o mesmo problema.

Comment: Mas se inspecionar o objeto "data", os dados estão sendo retornados?

Comment: Ele agora está aparecendo dois itens que estão nesta tabela PlanosServicos, porém no select aparece como undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você passa no `Json` `new` **Resultado**, esse campo que terá os valores da lista. Basta fazer dessa forma:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Load()
{
    var resultado = _context.PlanosServicos
    .Select(x => new { x.Id, x.Descricao });

    return Json(resultado);    
}
```

No `script:`

```
function ListarItens() {
    var url = "/PessoasServicos/Load";
    var selectbox = $('#cbplanos');
    selectbox.html("<option value='0'>Selecione</option>");
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {

            $.each(data, function (i, d) {
                selectbox.append('<option value="' + d.id + '">' + d.descricao + '</option>');
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Ele aparece dois dados no select, porém me aparece undefined.

Comment: experimenta trocar `d.Id` por `i.Id`

Comment: Como assim dois dados?

Comment: Deu certo, rs, estava passando errado no ajax, estava passando Id, e Descricao, foi apenas trocar para minúscula, e colocar o retorno igual auxiliou e deu certo, obrigado. Só que tem um problema, toda vez que eu chamo a função ele carrega, como posso colocar pra limpar ?

Comment: Editei a pergunta limpando ele em cada solicitação; Sobre o **id** acho que em outra pergunta sua falei sobre isso, é uma questão do "contrato", ele retorna as propriedades minúsculas, tem como mudar isso,